# How Do I Trigger An Off Ledger Action After A Corda Transaction Is Complete?

Tags: corda

I need to store some information from Corda (such as LinearId, Transaction Hash etc) in an off-ledger database (**not** an extra table in the node database) for subsequent external processing and downstream actions.

The key is that the code has to run after a *specific* flow (not **all** flows) has completed and *only* on one side/node of the transaction.

- The node trigger could write to the external database directly
- Or the trigger could write the data to a JMS queue for an external engine to pick up and process

How can I trigger an action after a flow has completed?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is with a responder flow. It depends on your use case but one thing you could do is just hold off on the return statement in the responder flow and just run some additional code or make an HTTP request from the responder flow.

Here's a code example: (you can see how it returns the subflow, but you can return it later and run some code after the return as well potentially)

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/obligation/flows/IOUSettleFlow.kt#L98-L113

More on responders flows: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-flows.html

Making an HTTP request from a flow: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Basic/flow-http-access/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flowhttp/HttpCallFlow.java#L35-L39

Comment: Can these be done _after_ the flow is complete though? How do I know that the transaction has completed successfully? I don't want to trigger an action and then find out later the transaction has been rolled back or failed to complete etc